# Iterative non-linear-least-squares opimizing a 3d to 2d projection

Tags: c++, matlab, image-processing, mathematical-optimization

please excuse my bad english this isn't my native language.

I try to solve a non-linear-least-squares-problem. I have two sets of points.
A set of 3D-points at time t and a set of 2D-imagepoints at time t+1, knowing the correspondences between them.

Now I have the following equation:

```
x(t+1) = ( x(t) - y(t)*rotz + z(t)*roty + tx )*f/(-x(t)*roty + y(t)*rotx+z(t)+tz)
y(t+1) = ( x(t)*rotz + y(t) - z(t)*rotx + ty )*f/(-x(t)*roty + y(t)*rotx+z(t)+tz)
```

The variable f is the focallength. I want to determine rotx, roty, rotz, tx, ty, tz so that the residual between the calculated points image points for t+1 and the known image points for t+1 gets minimal.

I take the euclidean distance between the image-points as error measurment.

```
E = sqrt( (x(t+1) - X)^2 + (y(t+1) - Y)^2 )
```

X and Y are the known 2d-image-points.

I calculated a matrix A with a row for every point correspendence and with partial derivatives for rotx, roty and so on in the columns.

I also calculated a column vector y with the results of E for a first estimation of rotx, roty and so on.

Now it is possible for me to calculate updates for the variables with:

```
delta = inv(A' * A) * A' * y
```

(A' means the transpose of A)
After updating i use the variables for a few more iterations.

But the algorithm is not converging, even if i set the first estimation with the expected solution. So I think I do something wrong.

Do I use the wrong approach? Can anyone give me a link to a good example or can explain his approach for this problem.

Thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. The calculated errors for the y-vector have to be negativ, otherwise the algorithm isnt converging.

```
y(i) = -E(i)
```